# Android - use a service as a timer?

Tags: android

I've read and re-read the documentation but I'm still now sure if using a service (and how) is the right way to keep a timer running.

I basically want to have a countdown timer, but I want it to run uninterrupted even if the app gets closed (and show up as an ongoing notification). When a certain activity in the app gets opened (resumed, opened, launched from clicking on the notification), I want it to be able to get the current value from the timer (no more frequent than once per second). If the app got closed, I still want the timer to be able to use/launch activities or other services (or access the database) of my app.

So if I understood the Android developer docs correctly, I should use a service that is started (because when started it should be able to do its thing even in the app gets closed) and bound (so an activity can get data from it). Then I searched Stack Overflow for similar topics and some people are recommending using IntentService (but can it send data to an activity?), or Handlers or even AlarmManager.

I'm really confused and I'd prefer to be able to pick the right approach from the start (rather than finish the app and then realize my approach wastes a lot of battery or something). The problem with documentation is it answers questions it thinks I have, so I have to ask a real person.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

1. When user starts your timer save current system timestamp.
2. In your UI: Every N milliseconds just read saved value and compare it to current timestamp. This give you a diff = elapsed time.
3. You do not need any timer/service/alarm manager. Every time user has return to your app you just do step №2 to show elapsed time.

Comment: Well that's certainly a lot simpler, but when the countdown reaches zero, I want the app to notify the user, even if the user or Android closed it. It also needs to show up as a notification (and preferably show the time remaining there as well). Are those things possible with your approach?

Comment: In that case you may run new Thread in your service to test current value of timer (for instance once per second). From this thread update your ongoing notification and notify user if timer reaches zero.

Comment: So I have to use a service? What the hell are threads? Back to Android docs I go

Comment: Android service works on UI thread, so if you want do anything in background you should do it on new Thread.